# Copy one object to another

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have 2 tables, user and userprofile. The userprofile table has a lot of fields similar to the user table. What I need to do is, on click of a button I need to copy all the fields of user table to userprofile table.

```
How can I do that?
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as a WPF question?

Answer (score 4):

Can you create a constructor on UserProfile that takes a User instance as a parameter and do it there? Not sure that is the best approach or if that violates good design. There is a utility called [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) out there that is good at inferring links between two seemingly unrelated objects, you may want to check that out because it is pretty cool.

Comment: Automapper is great for this kind of thing, especially if you don't want to create a constructor linking those two objects.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm not fully understanding your request.  But if you have two tables such as

```
DataTable user;
DataTable userProfiles;
```

And you want userProfiles to contain the same fields (or rather same columns) as table1 you can use

```
userProfiles= user.Clone();  // This will copy the schema of user table
userProfiles= user.Copy();   // This will copy the schema AND data of user table
```

Now if you want to copy on certain rows then you could do the following.

```
DataRow dr;
userProfiles= user.Clone();   // Do this first to create the schema.
foreach(DataRow row in user.Rows)
{
   if(...) // code to determine if you want to add this row
   {
      userProfiles.Rows.Add(row);  // This will add the same row from user table to userProfiles; Or you could create a new row using the 'dr' above and copy the data to provide a new DataRow
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is overly simplistic, but what's stopping you from

```
UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
profile.Name = UserModel[0].Name;
profile.OtherProperty = UserModel[0].OtherProperty;
...
DataServices.Save(profile);
```

If it's an encapsulation issue and you can't modify those properties, then Rob's answer about creating a constructor that takes a User object sounds appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My only concern was that there are a lot of fields in the table, so if there was some simple method out there, which could do it, that would be more easier and cleaner.

Comment: In this case I shall have to go and edit the code everytime I change fields in the table. Is there any way I can use Reflections, to achieve this?

Comment: @developer, have you looked at Rob's answer, I haven't looked at AutoMapper but both Chad and Rob seem to think it'll work for you.